# scaffold doesn't work well, the NEW method fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I've just executed this:

```
rails g scaffold Photos name:string description:string
```

and added paperclip to that model:

```
rails g paperclip Photo image
```

and when i go to `photos/new` i get this:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

What is the problem it may be? There is `@photo = Photo.new` in controller, and `form_for(@photo)` in new.html.erb

Thank you for ahy help!

Comment: what's the name of the file containing your model?

Comment: Did you run the migration and restart your server?

Comment: Yes, i did both of it, and i can actually see that there is a table `photos` in database. But in controller: `@photo = Photo.new`, and in view @photo is `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I thought that scaffolding always had to use the singular in the model name; pluralizing it leads to problems.  Thus it should have been Photo, not Photos:

```
rails g scaffold Photo name:string description:string
```